# React component cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to `React` and am currently working through learning how to make an appointment style web app, but there's a bug I don't quite understand how to fix.
The bug is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUserInput' of undefined

The relevant code is an appointments comp which serves as the parent component and an appointment_form comp as the child component.

The error occurs when the `AppointmentForm` tries to call `onUserInput` from its `handleChange` method. To me, the error sounds like I'm not calling the method properly but I haven't found a way to fix it. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

```
class Appointments extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          appointments: this.props.appointments,
          input_title: "Team Startup Meeting",
          input_apt_time: 'Tomorrow at 9am'
        };
    }

    handleUserInput(obj)
    {
        this.setState(obj);
    }

    handleFormSubmit()
    {
        var appointment = {title: this.state.title,
                      apt_time: this.state.apt_time}
        $.post('/appointments',
        {appointment: appointment});
    }

    render()
    {
        return (

            <div>
                <AppointmentForm input_title={this.state.input_title}
                    input_apt_time={this.state.input_apt_time}
                    onUserInput={this.handleUserInput} />

                <AppointmentsList appointments={this.props.appointments}
                onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class AppointmentForm extends React.Component {

    handleChange(e)
    {
        var name = e.target.name;
        obj = new Object();
        obj.name = e.target.value;
        this.props.onUserInput(obj);
    }

    handleSubmit(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onFormSubmit();
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Make an Appointment</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <input name="title" placeholder="Appointment Title"
                    value={this.props.input_title}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <input name="apt_time" placeholder="Date and Time"
                    value={this.props.input_apt_time}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type="submit" value="Make Appointment" />
                </form>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The apponintmentform component does not have a constructor to handle props, so props is not defined for that component?

Answer (score 1):

You should bind an instance of component to `this` of your `handleChange` method inside of components constructor:

```
class AppointmentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    ..........
}
```